# Adding 'data' to an NSMutable Array - Xcode

Tags: objective-c, arrays, nsarray

I want to add 'email' data to my `NSMutableArray` so every time the button is pushed it adds another email to the array, so I end up with an array of email addresses but can't seem to get it working.

I think my problem is I am reinitialising the array so clearing it out and maybe need to put the initialisation somewhere else..which I have tried.

The below code lets me add an address but each time the `IBAction` is called I think I am clearing the array, any pointers or help would be great

```
   @property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *mutable;

   @synthesize mutable;
   - (IBAction)array:(id)sender {

   mutable = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:self.person.email, nil];
   [mutable addObject:self.person.email];

   NSLog(@"ARRAY OF EMAILS %@",mutable);

   }
```

Comment: why downgrade when i ask a sensible question ??

Answer (score 0):

You are right - you are initializing the array each time the `array:` method is called. You can change the code to initialize it only once:

```
- (IBAction)array:(id)sender {
   if(!self.mutable) {
       self.mutable = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:self.person.email, nil];
   }
   [self.mutable addObject:self.person.email];

}
```

As a side note - you don't have to use `@synthesize` for this property. Read ["Adopting Modern Objective-C"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ModernizationObjC/AdoptingModernObjective-C/AdoptingModernObjective-C.html) for more details.

Comment: great answer but i have found that if i navigate away from that view then come back to it the ' array ' reinitializes ( clears itself )..sorry realised i didn't put that in my question..thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you use UIViewController? If yes then reset the array in viewDidAppear method.
If you are using the UIView, then create the custom method to reset the array and call from the parent viewController.